# Dire quelque chose qui n'est pas un propos

Tags: grammaire

Dans *Jean de Florette*, on trouve cette tournure :

[image: citation du livre]

> sa mère lui a dit la source

(Notez qu'en contexte il parle d'une source d'eau, pas d'une origine quelconque.)

Le sens en est bien évident, mais je ne vois pas comment *une source* peut être l'objet direct de *dire*. On dit des phrases, des propos, des salutations ... pas des choses concrètes. Je trouve pas d'exemplaire correspondant dans le dictionnaire. Est-ce que j'ai mal lu la phrase ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est un usage probablement influencé par le provençal, un peu comme l'expression précédente *se faire des imaginations*.

On peut dire *Sa mère **lui a dit le résultat*** (elle l'a informé du résultat) mais la phrase *Sa mère **lui a dit la source*** n'est pas naturelle en français contemporain. Ce serait plutôt *Sa mère lui a dit **pour** la source*, *lui a **parlé de la** source* ou ***l'a informé de l'existence de** la source*.

Answer (score 0):

Cet usage relève de la section « **I.B.1.a)α)** » du TLFi. (caractère gras de user LPH). Les syntagmes en caractère gras ci-dessous sont typiques et ont la même construction.

> (TLFi) **B.** − [Processus de la communication : valeurs sém.]
> **1.** Exprimer par la parole un propos.
> **a)** Emploi trans. dir.
> **α)** **Faire connaître par la parole**, énoncer, exprimer. Dire qqc. à, de qqn, dire que, dire comment, se dire à soi-même. Anton. partiel faire, écrire.
> SYNT. **Dire son nom** (cf. Flaub., Tentation, 1849, p. 290). Finir par dire (que). Un jour, après un emportement de son mari dont on a toujours ignoré la cause, cet homme finit par lui dire : « Allez dans votre chambre, madame! » (Barb. d'Aurev., Memor. A... B..., 1864, p. 438). **Dire la raison de** (cf. Balzac, Illus. perdues, 1843, p. 143). Avoir raison de dire. J'avais raison de dire qu'il n'était pas fait pour naître parmi les pauvres (Proust, Sodome, 1922, p. 847). **Dire des absurdités** (cf. Flaub., Corresp., 1857, p. 210, 211). **Dire des âneries** (cf. Gide, Faux-monn., 1925, p. 1087). Dire des riens (cf. Balzac, op. cit., p. 49). **Dire des sornettes** (cf. Duhamel, Terre promise, 1934, p. 60).

« Lui a dit la source » pourrait signifier « Lui a dit le nom de la source » ou « lui a dit de quelle source il s'agit » ou encore « Lui a dit où était la source ».

Answer (score 0):

Ugolin étant un paysan, Pagnol le fait s'exprimer dans un français auquel il manque des mots. Ici, la phrase correcte serait :

***Puisque** sa mère lui a dit **l'existence de** la source, il va la déboucher, et il ne partira jamais.*

Comment: En effet, *dire la source* et *dire l'existence* poussent les deux la même difficulté du point de vue syntaxique. Mais il est bon de savoir que le style de la phrase donne l'impression d'être elliptique.